# I'm trying to make a ship/match command and I can't figure out how to mention the 2nd user

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a ship command where, if you don't mention somebody the bot says to mention a user. if you mention one user, it ships you with them, and if you mention two users, then it ships the two users you've mentioned. I looked all over and now it just says "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" for "${user3.username}".

````
module.exports = {
    name: 'match',
    description: "match",
    execute(message, args){
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const PREFIX = 'ly?';
     if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'match')) {
            const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
            const user3 = message.mentions.users.array()[2]; 

        let replies = ["5% Compatible!", "3% Compatible!", "10% Compatible!", "14% Compatible!", "17% Compatible!", "20% Compatible!", "22% Compatible!", "25% Compatible!", "24% Compatible!", "27% Compatible!", "32% Compatible!", "36% Compatible!", "34% Compatible!", "39% Compatible!", "42% Compatible!", "45% Compatible!", "47% Compatible!", "51% Compatible!", "54% Compatible!", "56% Compatible!", "59% Compatible!", "58% Compatible!", "60% Compatible!", "63% Compatible!", "65% Compatible!", "64% Compatible!", "68% Compatible!", "70% Compatible!", "74% Compatible!", "78% Compatible!", "79% Compatible!", "80% Compatible!", "83% Compatible!", "86% Compatible!", "84% Compatible!", "89% Compatible!", "91% Compatible!", "93% Compatible!", "95% Compatible!", "97% Compatible!", "98% Compatible!", "99% Compatible!", "100% Compatible!", "destined to get married."];

        let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length))

    

            
                let (!args[1]) = "Please mention a user."   
        
           

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Does ${message.author.username} and ${user.username} match?`)
                .setDescription(`${message.author.username} and ${user.username} are __**${replies[result]}**__`)
                .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/HywjPEB.png')
                .setColor(0x7732a8);
        
                if(!args[2]) return message.channel.send(embed);
            
                   const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`Does ${user.username} and ${user3.username} match?`)
                    .setDescription(`${user.username} and ${user3.username} are __**${replies[result]}**__`)
                    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/HywjPEB.png')
                    .setColor(0x7732a8); 

                    
                    if(!args[3]) return message.channel.send(embed2);
                

            
            
            
            }
        
       }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the mentions collection extends Collection [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), try using `.first(2)` to grab the first 2 elements, then use `[1]`
To grab the 2nd mention

```
const user3 = message.mentions.users.first(2)[1];
```

Ofcourse you'll have to verify that there are 2 total mentions